# Windows 2003 Server cannot connect to SSL website

Tags: windows, validation, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a problem with a Windows 2003 server.  The server is fully service packed and has all the latest windows updates.

Our server cannot connect to a certain SSL web site.

I have checked the SSL certificate of the remote third party website and it all validates successfully.

I have even checked on another Windows 2003 server and that connects and validates the certificate correctly.

The server that is failing to connect is reporting the following when trying to connect:

> The remote server (url) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateChainErrors.  The signature of the certificate can not be verified.

It gets a handshake but then fails to validate the certificate.

Does anyone have any ideas on what is causing this problem ?

I've cleared the CRL cache and rebooted the server accordingly but the problem still persists.

I've installed Firefox on the server and that does not have any problems connecting to the SSL url and validates the certificate correctly.

It's just the Windows OS and IE8 that have the issue and are unable to connect.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: After a lot of further testing I can see that certain types of SSL certificates are not validating.

This url does not work but does work on our other server which is also windows 2003 with IE8.

https://www.ssllabs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Is the certificate using a SHA1 or SHA2 hash algorithm? Because Windows 2003 Server does not support SHA2 unless you run the hotfix from Microsoft.